# Sending a binary file over a Java Socket

Tags: java, sqlite, sockets, tcp

I have written a multi-client TCP server that has the dual purpose of sending Json (text based) command strings and also sending an SQLite database file to multiple clients.  Everything is working nicely except...  the database file uses the special character hex81 (decimal 129) for some internal purpose.  When I read the database file into a byte array, Java converts this character to decimal -127 because of Java's signed representation of bytes.  However the socket is actually transmitting this character as hex3F.  So when I receive the save the data in the client and save it to a file, the database is corrupt due to the presence of h3F chars instead of h81.

Why is this happening and how do I correct it?

Here is the complete code that I am using for the server (a new instance of this class is started by a separate TCPServer class whenever a client connects):

```
public class TCPServerThread extends Thread {

// Connect status constants
private final static int NULL = 0;
private final static int DISCONNECTED = 1;
private final static int DISCONNECTING = 2;
private final static int BEGIN_CONNECT = 3;
private final static int CONNECTED = 4;

private final static String END_SESSION = new Character((char)0).toString(); // Indicates the end of a session

// Connection state info
private int connectionStatus = DISCONNECTED;

private static StringBuffer txBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
private static ByteArrayOutputStream txBuffer2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 

private static File file;

// TCP Components
private ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
private Socket clientSocket = null;
private BufferedReader in = null;
private PrintWriter out = null;
private DataOutputStream out2 = null;
private String s = "";

private DecodeJson dj = new DecodeJson();
private boolean doRun;  


public TCPServerThread(Socket socket) throws IOException {

    doRun = true;
    clientSocket = socket;      
    changeStatusTS(BEGIN_CONNECT, true);

}

public void run() {

    while (doRun) {
        try { // run every ~10 ms
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {}

        if (Mainscreen.shutdown == true || TCPClient.close == true) 
            connectionStatus = DISCONNECTING;

        switch (connectionStatus) {

            case BEGIN_CONNECT:

                try {
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                    out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    out2 = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                    TCPServer.writers.add(out);             // add this socket to the connected clients list
                    changeStatusTS(CONNECTED, true);
                }
                // If error, clean up and output an error message
                catch (IOException e) {
                    cleanUp();
                    changeStatusTS(DISCONNECTED, false);
                }
                break;

            case CONNECTED:

                try {
                    // Send data
                    if (txBuffer.length() != 0) {
                        for (PrintWriter writer : TCPServer.writers) {
                            writer.print(txBuffer);
                            writer.flush();

                            if(writer.checkError()) {
                            closeSocket();
                            changeStatusTS(DISCONNECTING, true);

                            }else {
                                changeStatusTS(NULL, true);
                            }
                        }
                        txBuffer.setLength(0);
                    }

                    if (txBuffer2.size() != 0) {
                        byte[] result = txBuffer2.toByteArray();
                        System.out.println(result[745] + "," + result[746] + "," + result[747] + "," + result[748] + "," + result[749] + "," + result[750]);
                        out2.write(result);
                        out2.flush();                           
                        txBuffer2.reset();
                    }

                    // Receive data
                    if (in.ready()) {
                        s = in.readLine();
                        if ((s != null) &&  (s.length() != 0)) {
                            // Check if it is the end of a transmission
                            if (s.equals(END_SESSION)) {
                                changeStatusTS(DISCONNECTING, true);
                            }
                            // Otherwise, receive text
                            else {                                  
                                dj.receiveString(s);
                                changeStatusTS(NULL, true);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Socket error " + e);
                    cleanUp();
                    changeStatusTS(DISCONNECTED, false);
                }
                break;

            case DISCONNECTING:

                // Tell clients to disconnect as well
                if (out != null) {
                    out.print(END_SESSION);
                    out.flush();
                }
                // Clean up (close all streams/sockets)
                cleanUp();
                changeStatusTS(DISCONNECTED, true);
                break;

            default: break;
        }
    }
}

// Add command to text send-buffer
public static void sendString(String s) {

    synchronized (txBuffer) {
        txBuffer.append(s + "\n");
    }
}

// Add file data to binary send buffer
public static void sendFile(String filename) {

    synchronized (txBuffer2) {
        file = new File(filename);                      
        byte[] content = new byte[(int)file.length()];
        FileInputStream fin;
        try {
            fin = new FileInputStream(file);            
            fin.read(content);
            System.out.println(content[745] + "," + content[746] + "," +content[747] + "," +content[748] + "," + content[749] + "," + content[750]);
            txBuffer2.write(content);       
            fin.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException f) {
            f.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

private void changeStatusTS(int newConnectStatus, boolean noError) {

    // Change state if valid state
    if (newConnectStatus != NULL) {
        connectionStatus = newConnectStatus;
    }

}

private void closeSocket(){
    try {
        if (clientSocket != null) {
            clientSocket.close();
            clientSocket = null;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) { clientSocket = null; }   

}

// Cleanup for disconnect
private void cleanUp() {
    try {
        if (serverSocket != null) {
            serverSocket.close();
           serverSocket = null;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) { serverSocket = null; }

    try {
        if (clientSocket != null) {
            clientSocket.close();
            clientSocket = null;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) { clientSocket = null; }

    try {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
           in = null;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) { in = null; }

    if (out != null) {
        TCPServer.writers.remove(out);          // remove this socket for the connected sockets list
        out.close();
        out = null;
    }
    doRun = false;

}
```

}

Comment: come-on don't be lazy, don't just dump all of your code.

Comment: Wrapping `client.getOutputStream()` in both a PrintWriter and a DataOutputStream is asking for trouble.  Wrap it in one and only one Writer or OutputStream.

Comment: You can't use `Readers` and `Writers` if binary data is present. You are almost certainly going to have to completely rethink all this. I would use separate sockets for the text and the database stuff.

Comment: It seems that no matter what method I use, I end up with signed bytes in Java.  So the crux of my question is how do you get signed bytes to be transmitted as unsigned bytes in the socket output?

Comment: And in any event, why does h81 (-127) get transmitted as h3F (063)?  Forgive me but I can't see a relationship there.

Answer (score 0):

So as EJP suggested, the problem is due to using readers and writers.
The following code now works as expected (thanks for the tip EJP).  I will get around to addressing the issue raised by VGR about wrapping client.getOutputStream() in both a PrintWriter and a BufferedOutputStream, but for now the code works nicely (this is a work in progress).

```
public class TCPServerThread extends Thread {

// Connect status constants
private final static int NULL = 0;
private final static int DISCONNECTED = 1;
private final static int DISCONNECTING = 2;
private final static int BEGIN_CONNECT = 3;
private final static int CONNECTED = 4;

private final static String END_SESSION = new Character((char)0).toString(); // Indicates the end of a session

// Connection state info
private int connectionStatus = DISCONNECTED;

private static StringBuffer txBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
private static BufferedOutputStream out2 = null; 

private static File file;

// TCP Components
private ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
private Socket clientSocket = null;
private BufferedReader in = null;
private PrintWriter out = null;
private static BufferedInputStream fileData = null;
private String s = "";

private DecodeJson dj = new DecodeJson();
private boolean doRun;  


public TCPServerThread(Socket socket) throws IOException {

    doRun = true;
    clientSocket = socket;      
    changeStatusTS(BEGIN_CONNECT, true);

}

public void run() {

    while (doRun) {
        try { // run every ~10 ms
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {}

        if (Mainscreen.shutdown == true || TCPClient.close == true) 
            connectionStatus = DISCONNECTING;

        switch (connectionStatus) {

            case BEGIN_CONNECT:

                try {
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                    out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    out2 = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

                    TCPServer.writers.add(out);             // add this socket to the connected clients list
                    changeStatusTS(CONNECTED, true);
                }
                // If error, clean up and output an error message
                catch (IOException e) {
                    cleanUp();
                    changeStatusTS(DISCONNECTED, false);
                }
                break;

            case CONNECTED:

                try {
                    // Send data
                    if (txBuffer.length() != 0) {
                        for (PrintWriter writer : TCPServer.writers) {
                            writer.print(txBuffer);
                            writer.flush();

                            if(writer.checkError()) {
                            closeSocket();
                            changeStatusTS(DISCONNECTING, true);

                            }else {
                                changeStatusTS(NULL, true);
                            }
                        }
                        txBuffer.setLength(0);
                    }

                    if (fileData != null) {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) file.length()];
                        for (int read = fileData.read(buffer); read >=0; read = fileData.read(buffer)) out2.write(buffer, 0, read);
                        out2.flush();
                        fileData = null;
                    }

                    // Receive data
                    if (in.ready()) {
                        s = in.readLine();
                        if ((s != null) &&  (s.length() != 0)) {
                            // Check if it is the end of a transmission
                            if (s.equals(END_SESSION)) {
                                changeStatusTS(DISCONNECTING, true);
                            }
                            // Otherwise, receive text
                            else {                                  
                                dj.receiveString(s);
                                changeStatusTS(NULL, true);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Socket error " + e);
                    cleanUp();
                    changeStatusTS(DISCONNECTED, false);
                }
                break;

            case DISCONNECTING:

                // Tell clients to disconnect as well
                if (out != null) {
                    out.print(END_SESSION);
                    out.flush();
                }
                // Clean up (close all streams/sockets)
                cleanUp();
                changeStatusTS(DISCONNECTED, true);
                break;

            default: break;
        }
    }
}

// Add command to text send-buffer
public static void sendString(String s) {

    synchronized (txBuffer) {
        txBuffer.append(s + "\n");
    }
}

// Add file data to binary send buffer
public static void sendFile(String filename) {

    file = new File(filename);                      
    try {
        fileData = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void changeStatusTS(int newConnectStatus, boolean noError) {

    // Change state if valid state
    if (newConnectStatus != NULL) {
        connectionStatus = newConnectStatus;
    }

}

private void closeSocket(){
    try {
        if (clientSocket != null) {
            clientSocket.close();
            clientSocket = null;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) { clientSocket = null; }   

}

// Cleanup for disconnect
private void cleanUp() {
    try {
        if (serverSocket != null) {
            serverSocket.close();
           serverSocket = null;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) { serverSocket = null; }

    try {
        if (clientSocket != null) {
            clientSocket.close();
            clientSocket = null;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) { clientSocket = null; }

    try {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
           in = null;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) { in = null; }

    if (out != null) {
        TCPServer.writers.remove(out);          // remove this socket for the connected sockets list
        out.close();
        out = null;
    }
    doRun = false;

}
```

}

Comment: It beats me how continuing to use Readers and Writers constitutes taking the slightest notice of anything I've said here about not using them.

Comment: You suggested not using them for binary data.  So I am now only using streams for binary which solved the issue. However I still using readers and writers for the text transmissions which appears to be the standard way of doing it.  So what is your problem exactly?